# getting trace output from Visual Studio -- but not at application runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, trace, system.diagnostics

We have a C# console application that's working great.  It includes a 3rd party utility we use that logs to (system.diagnostics) trace.  We are successfully intercepting this trace using a custom trace listener, and write it to the database using Log4Net.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
  <listeners>
     <remove name="Default"/>
      <add name="myCustomTraceLog4NetListener" type="XXX.Log4netTraceListener,XXXXXX"/>
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

The problem is that this trace output is only generated and captured when running from visual studio directly, not from the command-line or clickonce.  When debugging with VS, we'll see it in the (debug) output window, and see that it's writing to the database -- but only when we run the app from within Visual Studio.  When calling the exact same executable from the command line, it won't capture this trace output whatsoever.  It's lost to the ether. But other log4net calls are working fine.

Are there any project/solution settings that would prevent trace from being written unless the app is launched interactively from VS?  Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `#define TRACE` to the top of one of your files that logs output and see whether you start getting the messages from that class.  According to Microsoft, the Trace class depends on the conditional compilation symbol TRACE, which is on by default in VS but may be getting lost during deployment depending on your settings...

Comment: Thanks, just tried that.  Confirmed that it was being compiled with the trace flag, and that the classes in question had the #define TRACE directive set.  Same result.